# Why we need to use lambda function in the last example in the api of "pandas.DataFrame.iloc"?

Tags: python, pandas

We can see the last example in  Click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
>>> df.iloc[:, lambda df: [0, 2]]
      a     c
0     1     3
1   100   300
2  1000  3000
```

I practise it and think we can abandon "lambda df:". I can understand lambda function. However, is there something useful about "lambda df:" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Selection By Callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

> **.loc**, **.iloc**, and also **[]** indexing can accept a callable as indexer. The callable must be a **function** with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing.

So need function for select by callable:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4),
                   index=list('abcdef'),
                   columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df1)
          A         B         C         D
a -0.217679  0.821455  1.481278  1.331864
b -0.361865  0.685609  0.573761  0.287728
c -0.235634  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943
d  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509 -0.189313
e  2.672172  0.464802  0.845930 -0.503542
f -0.963336  0.064969 -3.205040  1.054969
```

---

```
print (df1.iloc[:, lambda df1: [0, 2]])
          A         C
a -0.217679  1.481278
b -0.361865  0.573761
c -0.235634 -1.689625
d  0.016905  0.244509
e  2.672172  0.845930
f -0.963336 -3.205040

def f(df):
    return [0, 2]

print (df1.iloc[:, f])
          A         C
a -0.217679  1.481278
b -0.361865  0.573761
c -0.235634 -1.689625
d  0.016905  0.244509
e  2.672172  0.845930
f -0.963336 -3.205040
```

Comment: emm..It seems to be just a habit to use the callable, and the versatility is stonger. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamSkyrme - It is feature, but still up to you if use or not. In my opinion is not necessary use it,  but sometimes code should be one line, if use it. But if more readable for most people not sure.